# jQuery - exclude elements with any value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jquery, how can I select all elements that dont have attribute's value in a array of values?

Let's say I have the array `['a', 'b']` and inputs

```
<input value="a">
<input value="b">
<input value="c">
<input value="d">
```

How can I select only those with values `c` and `d`? Is there a way without `each()` using some kind of selector so I can use it for exampe with `find(selector)` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not()` pseudo selector

```js
let not = ['a', 'b'];
$(`input:not([value=${not[0]}],[value=${not[1]}])`).val(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input value="a">
<input value="b">
<input value="c">
<input value="d">
```

alternatively

```js
let not = ['a', 'b'];
$(`input:not(${not.map(prop => `[value=${prop}]`)})`).val(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input value="a">
<input value="b">
<input value="c">
<input value="d">
```

Comment: what if there are too many values in `not` array , can there be a way around it

Comment: @Dij `$(\`input:not(${not.map(prop => \`[value=${prop}]\`).join(",")})\`);`

Comment: interesting, what is the purpose of join() in the end.

Answer (score 6):

select all input using `$('input')` and then use `filter()`

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b'];

var inputs = $('input').filter((x,y) => !arr.includes($(y).val()));
console.log(inputs.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="a">
<input value="b">
<input value="c">
<input value="d">
```

Comment: That great, I didn't got the idea to look for a `filter()` function or similar. I was only trying to mix up some selector. Thanks!